# Javascript - need to open pop-up but don't refresh the main page on submit click

Tags: javascript, popup, submit

I am working on a piece of requirement of a page where it is needed to open a pop-up screen on a click of a hyper-link on a JSP page. The data displayed on that pop-up page  should be based on the form POSTED from the jsp page containing the link.

Also, this JSP page should not get refreshed while getting posted by clinking on link. This means the JSP contents should remain as it is - apparently user should not feel the page is submitted.

I have coded it but could not stop the page to get refreshed.

As of now I am using the Javascript function like:

```
function displayEmailPreview(mode){
    var url='/email_preview.do';

    //To Submit the form
    document.SelectForm.action=url;
    document.SelectForm.method='post';
    document.SelectForm.submit(); 

    //to open pop-up
    popup = window.open(url, '', 'width=500', 'height=500', 'resizable=yes', 'scrollbars=yes');
    return ;
}
```

**The problem with this code is:**

1. **it sbumits the page two times**
2. **the main JSP page gets refreshed as soon as it POSTS the form.**

   *I don't want to use AJAX as the development time will be increased.*

   **Is there any way to POST the form using this 'WINDOW.OPEN(....)' only, and avoid the submission  part from above code ?**

Answer (score 0):

try returning the Submit false

```
     document.SelectForm.action=url;
     document.SelectForm.method='post';
     document.SelectForm.submit();
     return false;
```

Comment: This does not works as due to some reason it fails to submit the form as well as it does not reached to the line:  popup = window.open(url, '', 'width=500', 'height=500', 'resizable=yes', 'scrollbars=yes'); and the pop-up does not appear . Any suggestion pls.

Answer (score 0):

I got is resolved by adding target='_blank'

So, the working code is:-

function displayEmailPreview(mode){
    var url='/email_preview.do';

```
//To Submit the form
document.SelectForm.action=url;
document.SelectForm.method='post';
document.SelectForm.submit(); 

//to open new window
   target="_blank";
```

}